# Using digest authentication with curl

Tags: c, libcurl

I developed a basic authentication with libcurl in this way:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://192.168.1.133:8080/myrep");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, "user");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, "passwd");
```

I want to develop also the digest authentication with libcurl.

How to do it.

Did Libcurl support this behaviour

1) --> client send to the server a http request without authentication fields

2) <-- server respond with 401 need digest authentication and providing the `authrealm`

3) --> client send the same http message with digest authentication using the received `authrealm`

4) <-- In case of success. The server send authentication success and the client detect it via libcurl

5) <-- In case of failure. The server resend the 401 message and The client detect it via libcurl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, libcurl supports it. See [CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTHTTPAUTH) and then especially the CURLAUTH_DIGEST bit.